# $(window).resize() and Print Preview Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I have a very simple piece of code that refreshes window after resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

When I try to open Print Preview Mode (Ctrl + P) in Chrome, it refreshes it as well. Any ideas how to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And thanks for the properly written text, and the properly indented code. One small note though, you do not need to say "thanks" here, we're all willing to answer already. It's even considered noise in the question. Have fun on SO!

Comment: Out of interest, why is there a need to reload after resizing the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine print actions there are two events: `beforeprint` and `afterprint`. Using these event it's possible to set some flag in `onbeforeprint` that print activated and check this flag in `resize` handler.

```
window.onbeforeprint = function() {
    print = true;
};
```

Unfortunately Chrome [doesn't support these events yet](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19937). As workaround in Chrome `matchMedia` may be used:

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
    } else {
        console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
    }
});
```

So solution for Chrome might be like this:

```
var print = false;
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        print = true;
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(event) {
  if (!print) {
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

After this `print` flag should be reset in `onafterprint` to allow further window resizes.

More info about this approach - http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/.