# Chrome Print Dialog Closing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, printing, resize

Why is the following page un-printable on google chrome? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73zu1g4g/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="f" src="http://placehold.it/350x1500?q=1"></iframe>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("resize",function () {
       var f = document.querySelector("#f");
        f.src = f.src+"1";
        f.style.height="2000px";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can't replicate the issue, I am using `Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, and my screen size is `1920x1080`

Even more interesting, it still can't print when you have `display: none` set. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73zu1g4g/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="f" src="http://placehold.it/350x1500?q=1" style="display: none"></iframe>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("resize",function () {
       var f = document.querySelector("#f");
        f.src = f.src+"1";
        f.style.height="2000px";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

The `f.style.height` is not necessary, the main issue is the iframe src change (a widget needs a size parameter in its location)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29297406/6429774

Comment: @Phil I'll look into that, but it seems a bit odd to have a chrome specific event listener just for detecting the print

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with your resize handler. If you remove that code, it works fine. I believe you can accomplish what you're looking for in a CSS media query instead:

```
<iframe id="f" src="https://placehold.it/350x1500?q=1"></iframe>

@media print {
  #f { height: 2000px }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7x9sdf79/1/

Comment: This is true, but this code is a stripped down version from a website I am working on. The key bit is the iframe src